# DNS records on suffix of domain not subdomain

Tags: dns, subdomain, cloudflare

I use Cloudflare for DNS. Is it technically possible to set records on the extended domain rather than subdomain.

EG: domain.com -> Server 1 and domain.com/abc -> Server 2. The practical side effect is the root switches from '/' to '/suffix' at the DNS level

Currently its setup to use subdomains eg: abc.domain.com

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible to do with DNS. However, you could proxy that path to Server 2. On NGINX, this will be a `proxy_pass` to Server 2 in the `location /abc` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. You can use iFrame or redirect.